# odoo form view update another field's value from js

Tags: javascript, odoo-11

I have a custom widget that should set the value of another field in my model. I implemented this by doing an RPC from JS to a setter in my model for the field. This works, but the new value is not immediately shown in the UI. So to see the value I have to refresh the page.

Is there a way to update the form view using JS?

What is the correct way of setting a value inside the model from a custom widget?

**Example**

I have a field A and a field C. C has a custom widget for example a button. When clicking the button the value of A should be changed. Question is how do I update field A from the custom widget of field B?

**Note**

I am on Odoo 11, which changed a lot of the JS API, I think

Answer (score 2):

I checked difference between ways of updating fields: yours and the basic keyboard input way. Difference is when you update your way, server doesn`t call onchange.

**js file**

```js
odoo.define('theme_address.theme', function (require) {
    "use strict";

var Widget= require('web.Widget');
var widgetRegistry = require('web.widget_registry');

var changeTitle = function() {
        opp_name.value = value_input.value;
    };
    
var MyWidget = Widget.extend({

    template: 'sigPad',

    events: {
        'click .your_class': 'change_opp_name',
    },

    change_opp_name: function () {
        var opp_name = document.getElementById("o_field_input_21");
        var value_input = document.getElementById('value_input');
        var change_opp_name_button = document.getElementById('change_opp_name_button');
        var event = new Event('change');
        change_opp_name_button.addEventListener('change', changeTitle(), false);
        opp_name.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
});

widgetRegistry.add(
    'my_widget', MyWidget
);

return MyWidget;

});
```

**template**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<templates>
    <t t-name="sigPad">
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="value_input" class="form-control" style="max-width: 400px;  width: 150px"/>
            <input type="button" id="change_opp_name_button" class="your_class" value="Submit"/>
        </div>
    </t>
</templates>
```

I`ll continue looking into more methods of doing that, i`ve been told there are at least 2 more ways to update it like this.